# How to correctly create interfaces with decomposed components in React + TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have tried to create simple decomposed components and created interface, but i faced with a fact that all my declared params in interface were not necessarily:

```
export interface ImagesState {
    images?: any[];
    loading?: boolean;
    error?: null | string;
    page?: number;
    limit?: number;
    pages?: any[];
}
```

**Images.tsx**, here main component with decomposition

```
const Images:FC = props => {
    const {page, limit, images, loading, error} = useTypeSelectors(state => state.images)
    const {fetchImages} = useActions()

const pages = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

useEffect(() => {
    fetchImages(page, limit)
}, [page])

if (loading) {
    return <h1>loading...</h1>
}
if (error) {
    return <h1>{error}</h1>
}
return (
    <div>
        <ImagesList images={images}/>
        <ImagesPages pages={pages} page={page} />
    </div>
);
```

};

**ImagesList.tsx**, inner component

```
const ImagesList:FC<ImagesState> = ({images}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {images?.map(i => (
                <img key={i.url} src={i.url} width={50} height={50} alt=""/>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};
```

**ImagesPages.tsx:**, another inner component

```
const ImagesPages:FC<ImagesState> = ({pages, page}) => {
    const {setImagesPage} = useActions()
    return (
        <div>
            {pages?.map(p => (
                <div
                    key={p}
                    onClick={() => setImagesPage(p)}
                    style={{
                        border:p === page ? '3px solid blue': '1px solid gray'
                    }}
                >
                    {p}
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};
```

**What I did wrong?**

Comment: What is `useTypeSelectors`?

Comment: *"What I did wrong?"* What **is** wrong? What problem are you seeing? Do you get an error? What behavior do you expect, and what behavior do you get instead?

Comment: I am trying to write code correctly, and just ask is it a common case if i faced with all params that are not necessarily

Comment: useTypeSelectors is custom hook: 
export const useTypeSelectors: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand that comment. What does "if i faced with all params that are not necessarily" mean?

Comment: by decomposition i meant dividing components on more little components

Comment: My interface has all params not necessarily (with '?' sign). Is it a common case or i did something wrong

Comment: It depends entirely on whether you want those properties to be optional. If they should be, then that's fine. If they shouldn't be, it isn't. There is no one rule for it.